# How to switch text in <p> using JS and onkeydown event

Tags: javascript, html

I have some code but it isn't working, probably because of some mistake in JS code. I have some text in English and I want to switch text to another language by keydown ENTER so:

1. When page loads default is English
2. When pressing ENTER language text should change on Dutch
3. When pressing ENTER again language text should change on Spain
4. When pressing ENTER again back to English and it will be a loop

So everytime that I press ENTER I want to get result with changing text

English -> Dutch -> Spain -> English -> Dutch -> Spain etc

my broken code below :)

```
<p id="language">English</p>

function myFunction() {
  var demo = document.getElementById("language").value;

  switch(demo) {
    case "English":
      text = "Dutch";
    break;
    case "Dutch":
    text = "Spain";
    break;
    case "Spain":
    text = "English";
    break;
  }
  document.getElementById("language").innerHTML = text;
}

document.onkeydown = function () {
    if (window.event.keyCode == '13') {
        myFunction();
    }
}
document.getElementById("language").innerHTML = text;
```

Comment: Fixed: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/wqnfut56/ (note that if you press F12 and go to the console tab, the browser will tell you exactly what's wrong with your code. you don't have to fly blind)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some mistakes in your code.

1. You have missed to add script tags around your JS function.
2. you have missed to define variable `text`.
3. You have used `.value` in that `document.getElementById("language")`. it should be `.innerHTML`

```html
<p id="language">English</p>

<script>
var text;

function myFunction() {
  text = document.getElementById("language").innerHTML;

  switch (text) {
    case "English":
      text = "Dutch";
      break;
    case "Dutch":
      text = "Spain";
      break;
    case "Spain":
      text = "English";
      break;
  }
  document.getElementById("language").innerHTML = text;
}

document.onkeydown = function() {
  if (window.event.keyCode == '13') {
    myFunction();
  }
}

 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `text` variable is present within the `myFunction()`. The scope of your `text` variable is within your `myFunction()` and you are accessing it outside the function - `document.getElementById("language").innerHTML = text;`

Declare `text` variable outside of your `myFunction` to make it globally accessible.

```js
var text = "English";

function myFunction() {
    var demo = document.getElementById("language").innerHTML;

    switch(demo) {
        case "English":
        text = "Dutch";
        break;
        case "Dutch":
        text = "Spain";
        break;
        case "Spain":
        text = "English";
        break;
    };

    document.getElementById("language").innerHTML = text;
}

document.onkeydown = function () {
    if (window.event.keyCode == '13') {
        myFunction();
    }
}
document.getElementById("language").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<p id="language">English</p>
```

Comment: because your code is not working. you have used `document.getElementById("language").value` but that is a `p` tag. you have to use `.innerHTML` to get the content.

Comment: just hit `enter` in my snippet and see. you will see the difference

Comment: @SyedMohamedAladeen - Ohh I missed the functionality, I just explained the reason for getting the error.